# How to avoid a JSON object with numbers as keys getting interpreted as an array when uploading to Firebase Real Time Database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Typescript with Enums to create some dynamic object structure. These enums are represented as numbers in the object, not as their string value, which I want to keep as it is. When I am uploading these objects to the Firebase RTDB, the objects are misinterpreted as arrays.

Enum example in typescript

```
enum TableState {
  Standby = 0,
  Idle,
  In_Game,
  Maintenance,
}
```

Javascript object I want to upload to the Google RTDB

```
configuration_per_state: {
  [TableState.Idle]: {
    brightness: 10,
  },
  [TableState.In_Game]: {
    brightness: 10,
    duration: 20 * 60, //20 minutes,
  }
}
```

which is the following stringified JSON:

```
{
    "configuration_per_state": {
        "1": {
            "brightness": 10
        },
        "2": {
            "brightness": 10,
            "duration": 120
        }
    }
}
```

I now faced the issue that when uploading to the Firebase Real Time Database, the object gets interpreted as an array. So when I want to retrieve the data the object structure was changed by the DB.

Code to upload the object:

```
const createInitialConfigInDb = (
  tableConfig: InitialTableState): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid
    db.ref(`config/${userId}/general`).set(tableConfig).then((data) => {
      //success callback
      resolve(data)
    }).catch((error) => {
      //error callback
      reject(error)
    })
  })
};
```

Resulting JSON after uploading to the database and downloaded from the RTDB:

```
{
  "configuration_per_state" : [ null, {
    "brightness" : 10,
  }, {
    "brightness" : 10,
    "duration" : 1200,
  } ],
}
```

Firstly I don't get why there is an entry "null" as the first array entry ...
And secondly is there an easy way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase interprets you data as an array, and the `null` it adds indicates that there's no element at index `0` in the array.

Firebase Realtime Database's array coercion/interpretation cannot be configured.

The only way to prevent it from interpreting your data as an array, is by not using numeric keys.

My common solution is to prefix such keys with a short, constant string value. For example:

```
{
  "configuration_per_state" : {
    "key_1": 
      "brightness" : 10,
    }, 
    "key_2": {
      "brightness" : 10,
      "duration" : 1200,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. Any idea how to do this best with my dynamic enum object creation I want to keep? Changing all enums to strings seems like not a good solution for the web app. Maybe changing the keys right before the upload and again when downloading them? But this also does not seem a very good solution to me. But it sounds to me I do not really have other possibilities, do I?

Comment: `"key_"+[TableState.Idle]: { ... }`?

Comment: Is another idea, I can consider. Will have to decide which one I take then. 
But given that the question is answered. Thanks.